# What is the Best way to find AND-Product of all the possible pairs of large array?

Tags: java, python-3.x, algorithm

The given array is too big contains 10^6 elements approx.

Already know traditional way of traversing each possible pair, but i want some more efficient way/trick.

```
int prod = 0, arr[]= {1,4};

for(int x = 0; x<arr.length;x++) {
    for(int y = x;y<arr.length; y++) {
        prod += arr[x] & arr[y];
    }
}

System.out.println(prod);
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:python-3.x]?

Comment: You are already avoiding double computing duplicates across the diagonal, and I think any further optimization might depend on what the data in the array looks like.

Comment: @JacobG. I want it to be done either in python or in java.

Comment: Why does the title (and the variable name) say product when the operator is `+=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Count the occurrences of each bit

int[] bitcounts = new int[32];
for (int x=0; x<arr.length; ++x) {
    int val = arr[x];
    for (int bit=0; bit<32; ++bit) {
        if ((val & (1<<bit)) != 0) {
            bitcounts[bit]++;
        }
    }
}

// If a bit appears in n entries, then it appears in n(n+1)/2 pairs
// (counting the pair of each item with itself)

int result = 0;
for (int bit=0; bit<32; ++bit) {
   long pairs = ((long)bitcounts[bit]) * (bitcounts[bit]+1) / 2;
   result += ((int)pairs) * (1<<bit);
}
return result;
```

Comment: This method doesn't providing the appropriate result. Here is an example:

If there is an ARRAY ={1,2,3}

then RESULT should be 9.

EXPLANATION: And-product(1,1)+And-product(1,2)+And-product(1,3)+And-product(2,2)+And-product(2,3)+And-product(3,3).

Comment: Oh, if you want to count the diagonal, then its n(n+1)/2.  I'll adjust the code

Comment: Thank! now its working correctly and also its the quickest way i found yet.

Answer (score 0):

If `arr[x]`=0, you can skip the whole inner loop for that value of `x` (since 0&*y*=0 no matter what *y* is.

Answer (score 0):

The diagonal is an identity.

```
prod = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    int ax = arr[x];
    for(int y = x + 1; y <arr.length; y++) {
        prod += ax & arr[y];
    }
    prod += arr[x];
}
```